# Clearcase Remote client unable to creare view and already existing view

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I was updating view in CCRC, which is not working hanging up and showing loading, while taking code update, then i restarted clear case it was not working properly, not showing current views, unable to create a new view...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to ask an admin to check the logs:

- on the CCRC server to see if this is a (web) server issue or on the view server managed there.
- on the ClearCase server to check if all the services (vob_server) all still up.

(specific CCRC versions are also know to have loading issue, as in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21392572) for CCRC7.1)

You can also check if you are the only one with that issue.
In that case it is a client issue, which means you can try and install CCRC again (in another path in order to not modify your current setup), and check if the issue persists.

Make sure this isn't a credential problem (which can happen when you have to change your login password on a regular basis).

In fact, The [OP SCK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198166/sck) [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642004/clearcase-remote-client-unable-to-creare-view-and-already-existing-view/14642164#comment20647676_14642164):

> I talked with my admin, [it was an] issue with my login credentials re-created user profile in windows and it started working fine.

Comment: i am alone having issues, seems we cannot have 2 CCRC's in a machine with different location, it is showing CCRC already installed. So uninstalled and gain installed CCRC still no luck.

Comment: @SCK do you enter your primary group correctly? (https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccperspective_configuregrps.htm) What is the version of CCRC and of ClerCase (on the server) that you are using? Was it working at any point before today ?

Comment: I am using CCRC Version: 7.0.1.D061004, i don't know about CC server (which is beyond my scope) version might be same, i am just an end user.

Comment: @SCK was it working at any point in time before this question?

Comment: i talked with my admin, issue with my login credentials re-created user profile in windows it started working fine.

Comment: @SCK Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.